# Poetry: Can we use `explicit` priority for chained dependencies?

Tags: python, python-poetry

Let's say I have three Python packages `A`, `B` and `C`. All of them are managed by poetry and published in a private package repository.
Package `B` depends on `A`, package `C` depends on `B`, and all of them have additional dependencies on packages from the PyPI repository.

Using poetry 1.5.1 I tried this setup, which doesn't work for me (I've omitted irrelevant parts of the `pyproject.toml` files for brevity):

`B/pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
A = {version = "*", source = "my-private"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "primary"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my-private"
url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/65473942/-/packages/pypi/simple"
priority = "explicit"
```

`C/pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
B = {version = "*", source = "my-private"}

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "primary"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my-private"
url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/65473942/-/packages/pypi/simple"
priority = "explicit"
```

When I run `poetry lock` in project `B`, then it works fine. I mean, the package `A` is found in `my-private` repository and all other dependencies are found in PyPI.

But when I run `poetry lock` in project `C`, then the command fails because it cannot find the package `A`. It seems to me that it is trying to install `A` from PyPI, but there is no such package.

**My questions:**

- Is this behavior intentional or is it a poetry bug?
- Is it possible to use `explicit` priority for repositories containing packages with transitive dependencies (`C` depends on `B` which depends on `A` - all stored in private repository)?

The only solution I have found so far is not to use `explicit` priority.
If I change the priority of `my-private` repository to `default` (and remove the `source` attribute in the dependencies section), then it works - all packages are searched in `my-private` repository, and if they are not found there, then PyPI is used as a "fallback".

But I still wonder if the `explicit` priority can be used in this case, because it seems safer to me (poetry will fail if my package is not found in `my-private` repository and a package with the same name from PyPI will not be installed by mistake).
My current solution also does not work properly when I use more than one private repository (if they contain packages with the same name).